# How to fixed "do you want to allow this app from an unknown publisher to make changes to your device project" warning?

Tags: c++, qt

I made a project using Qt creator. After deploying my project every time I open my project there is a popup window showing that warning. I submit my file for malware analysis.Is it possible to remove that warning or first time only show..

This is my manifest file:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

my Deploy step:

```
1. Build my project in release mode.
2.Copy static lib in same folder.
3.C:\mt -manifest C:\QtProject\projectName\app.manifest.xml -outputresource:ProjectName.exe;1
4..\windeployqt   C:\QtProject\build-PprojectName-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_MinGW_64_bit-Release\release\projectName.exe
5.Navigate to the deploy/windows folder.
6.C:\Qt\Tools\QtInstallerFramework\4.5\bin\binarycreator -c config/config.xml -p packages -f projectNameSetup
```

Comment: (1) Right click the exe > properties ... there is checkbox on one of the tabs that says something like "...do you want to allow this unknown program to run...". Or (2) get a code-signing certificate and sign the program.

Comment: Get a code signing certificate. Sign your application.

Comment: How buy code signing certificate, Which is best?

Comment: @JesperJuhl This will not help. This will just change the window's color from yellow to blue :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `requireAdministrator` in your manifest. You can run `Qt Creator` as administrator to get rid of this window.